# Sort and source configuration files from one of two directories

Tags: shell, zsh

In a zsh I want to loop over all files in a configuration files' directory (`/etc/myapp/`) to source them. The files should be sourced in order and are named with two leading digits `10-early 40-middle 99-last`. A user without write permission to `/etc` should be allowed to extend the list of files and override the global ones. This is done by creating a `$HOME/.myapp` directory. The user files should be sourced in order with the global files, i.e. `/etc/myapp/10-early $HOME/.myapp/20-rightafter /etc/myapp/40-middle $HOME/.myapp/90-late /etc/myapp/99-last`. A user should also be allowed to override global files, i.e. when `$HOME/.myapp/99-last` exists, then `/etc/myapp/99-last` should be skipped.

As answerded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10981499) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26825), I create an array with all the config files and then use `basename` on the array ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9516801)) to restrict it to the `NN-lllll` part and sort them. Eventually each file gets sourced from `$HOME/.myapp` if it exists there, and from `/etc/myapp` otherwise.

```sh
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/10981499
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26825
thefiles=(/etc/myapp/* $HOME/.myapp/*(N))
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/9516801
uniquified=( $( for f in "${thefiles[@]}" ; do basename $f ; done | sort -V | uniq) )
for f in $uniquified
do
# -r checks if file exists and is readable
  if [[ -r $HOME/.myapp/$f ]]
  then
    source $HOME/.myapp/$f
  else
    source /etc/myapp/$f
  fi
done
```

Is there a more elegant solution and should I be aware of errors I need to catch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `sort -V | uniq` into `sort -uV`.

Note that the `-V` flag of `sort` doesn't exist in BSD.
Consider replacing it with `-n` if that's good enough.

The `if` inside the loop can be written more compactly as:

```
[[ -r $HOME/.myapp/$f ]] && source $HOME/.myapp/$f || source /etc/myapp/$f
```

You could also replace `source` with `.` which is equivalent.